# E11000 duplicate key error collection in PyMongo

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am developing my app with Djnago and for database mongo db . Its basically a subscription buying platform. On 2nd time buying a subscription Its throwing error .

In order model I have:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField(OrderSubscription)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    amount =  models.FloatField()
    billing_address = models.ForeignKey(
        'Address', related_name='billing_address', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    payment = models.ForeignKey(
        'Payment', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    coupon = models.ForeignKey(
        'Coupon', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    being_delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    received = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    refund_requested = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    refund_granted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

When someone brought a subscription and want to buy again another Sub Its throwing duplicate key error where Its creating another order table with the same user.

```
def finalcheckout(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        subscription = get_object_or_404(Subscription, slug = request.POST.get("sub_slug"))
        order_subscription, created = OrderSubscription.objects.get_or_create(
        subscription=subscription,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
         )
        order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user)
        order.subscriptions.add(order_subscription)
        messages.info(request, "This subscription was added to your cart.")
        return redirect("core:order-summary")
```

Error:

> Params: [2, None, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 2, 12, 26, 53, 481937),
>   None, False, None, None, None, None, False, False, False, False]
>   Pymongo error: {'writeErrors': [{'index': 0, 'code': 11000,
>   'keyPattern': {'backup_id': 1}, 'keyValue': {'backup_id': None},
>   'errmsg': 'E11000 duplicate key error collection:
>   hostmanager.subscription_order index:
>   subscription_order_backup_id_79d0cc4e_uniq dup key: { backup_id: null
>   }',

Answer (score 0):

The exception occurs at this line of your code,

**order = Order.objects.create(user=request.user)**

which means that the model you are using only has mere text fields with no primary key whatsoever